# How can I across the values in a field by Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: report, pentaho, report-designer

I am a beginner..  I want to know how can I across the values in a field by Pentaho Report Designer? Does it support this?  Like this :
In Database

```
name   id               
 a      1              a   b   c
 b      2     to       1   2   3 
 c      3
```

THX  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in the cutting edge Pentaho reporting, see here:

http://www.on-reporting.com/blog/a-quick-introduction-to-crosstabs-in/

Another alternative is if your data can be modelled in a Mondrian schema then use the OLAP input data source and you can pivot your data however you see fit!

Last Alternative - use the Kettle option as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) via the [row normalizer](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/eai/row+normalizer) and [row denormalizer](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+De-normalizer) steps.

Comment: I tend to achieve that in the report layer .I’ll try that. THANKS